# Serial Connection Issues

Tags: windows-8, drivers, serial-port

I have a Radionics rfid badge reader on my desk which is supposed to interface with our badge software (Stanley PAC) which is installed on my computer.

I am using a docking station (also HP) which works with the badge reader on another system (still relatively new) so I know it works with the docking station and on Windows 7 (I am on Windows 8.1 now)

I cannot seem to find out how to configure serial devices on a new system. Here is what I see from devmgmt.msc:

[image]

Can anyone provide steps for me to:

1) Find the appropriate settings from the other system which enabled it to use the serial device
2) Tell windows that there is a serial device and how to use it?

All I have for hardware information on the serial device is that it is 'Radionics' brand "Readykey" type of device and 'K6100' is written on it as well. When I plug in the device nothing appears to happen in Windows (no beeps, etc.)

I have unfortunately not seen anything from Radionics which talks about configuring this older device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=(

Turns out the software had a flag to 'enable serial devices'. Once enabled the device started working and software acknowledge the badge scanner. TIL software settings are important.